# How to determine the database host from ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe 'sql.active_record'

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, notifications, activesupport

I am using Notifications in Rails 3 (as described in this railscast http://asciicasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3) to log slow sql queries produced on my app.  But these include queries that come from my read-only database.  Therefore I would like to know if there is a way to tell which database the sql query is being executed on.  Any help is much appreciated.  My code is below.

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe 'sql.active_record' do |*args|
  begin
    event = ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event.new(*args)
    if event.duration > 250
      Rails.logger.error "[SLOW QUERY] | #{event.duration}ms | #{event.payload[:sql]}
    end
  rescue
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The key point you may be missing is that the payload contains a `connection_id` element, which is just a Ruby object_id. So, you should be able to do something like this:

```
def get_connection_host(payload)
  connection_object_id = payload[:connection_id]
  return nil unless connection_object_id.present?

  connection_object = ObjectSpace._id2ref(connection_object_id)
  return nil unless connection_object

  #If the connection object descends from ActiveRecord::Base, it'll have this.
  if connection_object.respond_to?(:connection_config)
    return connection_object.connection_config[:host]
  end

  #If we're dealing with straight SQL, the AR connection adapter will be the connection object and have this variable.
  if connection_object.instance_variable_defined?('@connection_options')
    return connection_object.instance_variable_get('@connection_options').try(:[], :host)
  end
rescue => e
  #log error, raise, do whatever is appropriate in your context
end
```

This code isn't super future-proof, relying on instance variables, and I'm not 100% sure what would happen if the connection object had already been garbage collected. However, it should give you some ideas.

The suggestion to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` makes sense, but I don't *think* it's reliable if you're working in an application that connects to multiple databases, which is exactly where you might really want to do some type of filtering by the host or database name.

Answer (score -1):

You can access this through `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.host`. If this returns `nil`, you're connecting to a local database, probably via a socket. If that's the case, then you can assume the host is `localhost`.